# What is being checked in this function?

Tags: php, arrays, function, arguments

I'm trying to port some PHP code over to C#, and I ran across a PHP function of this form:

```
function DoStuff($myVar, array $myArray1, array $myArray2 = array())
{
    // some code not involving $myArray2

    if ($myArray2)
    {
        // do things with $myArray2, but if I arrive here, what
        // condition was met?
    }
}
```

My best guess (which may be completely wrong) after looking over a number of appropriate pages in php.net as to what's happening:

- `$myArray2` is optional, but if nothing is provided the array goes in empty
- The `if` conditional checks to see whether `$myArray2` was passed in with one or more elements

Is this correct?  If not, what is correct?  Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, this is correct. The function will also throw a fatal error if something that is not an array is passed for `$myArray1` or `$myArray2`.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct and here is an explanation:

The type-hint `array` says that `$myArray2` can only accept an array. The default value of `array()` says that `$myArray2` is optional and, if it is not passed, an empty array will be assigned.

Given that the only thing that `$myArray2` could be at the time of the `if` conditional is an array, you can confirm what will be accepted by type casting to a boolean. In this case, an array is always converted to true unless it has no elements in which case it is false.

**Aside:** You should be careful to note that whilst it is currently illegal to pass NULL in as a parameter to both `$myArray1` and `$myArray2`, it is legal to set a default value of `$myArray2` as NULL. In that case, you could also pass in NULL to that parameter. Additionally, the conditional would then also be checking that the parameter was not set to NULL.